# How to merge array into JSON array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs

I have a JSON file that I need to add Comments into and then update the file.
I've created an array for the new comments

```js
//ADDING NEW COMMENTS
//add new comment within project
$scope.updatecomments = [];
$scope.addnewcomment = function() {
    $scope.updatecomments.push({
        "Author": "test",
        "Text": $scope.NewComment
    })
}
```

I can post the new comments into the JSON file but it overrides the past comments.
I have tried to merge the older comments with the new comments with the following

```js
$scope.updatecomments = [];
$scope.addnewcomment = function() {
    $scope.updatecomments.push({"Author": "test" ,"Text": $scope.NewComment}).concat($scope.Comments, $scope.updatecomments);
}

$scope.updatecomments = [].concat($scope.updatecomments, 
    $scope.projectDetails.Comments);
$scope.addnewcomment = function() {
    $scope.updatecomments.push({
        "Author": "test",
        "Text": $scope.NewComment
    });
}
```

I also tried making a new function that when called  combines the two and then post the combined array

```js
$scope.combine = [];
$scope.combineComments = function (){
    var jsonStr = $scope.projectDetails.Comments;
    var obj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
          
    obj['Comments'].push({"Author":"Test","Text":$scope.NewComment});
          jsonStr = JSON.stringify(obj);
    }
}
```

I have been going over this for the past few days now and can't seem to get it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**

Sample Data of already existing data in JSON file

```json
{
    "Comments":[{
        "Author": "John Doe", 
        "Text": "Work completed"
     }]
}
```

Want to add to this (is from html input text tag) stored as NewComment

```json
{
    "Comments":[{
        "Author": "Test",
        "Text": "Project flagged"
    }]
}
```

**Edit 2**
This is how I'm getting my projects data

```
/FIND PROJECTS - ADD TO LIST
  $scope.projectList = [];
    for (var id = 0; id < 30; id++) {
      var targetURL = 'https://happybuildings.sim.vuw.ac.nz/api/sooleandr/project.'+id+'.json';
      $http.get(targetURL).then(
        function successCall(response){
          $scope.projectList.push(response.data);
        }
      );
    }
```

I then use this to access the selected information

```
//script
$scope.showData = function(x){
 $scope.projectDetails = x;
 };
//html
<ul class = 'pList'>
   <li ng-repeat = 'x in projectList' class = 'pbList'>
     <button class = 'pbutton' ng-click = 'showData(x)'>
       <label ng-model ='pID'>Project ID: </label>{{x.ProjectID}} <br>
       <label id ='pName'>Project Name: </label> {{x.Name}} <br> 
       <label id ='bID'>Building ID: </label>{{x.BuildingID}}<br>
  <label id ='sDate'>Start Date: </label>{{x.StartDate}}
      </button>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Then I have the following variables to post

```
$scope.updateProject = function (projectDetails){
  
  var updateproject = {
    "ProjectID":$scope.projectDetails.ProjectID,
    "Name":$scope.projectDetails.Name,
    "BuildingID":$scope.projectDetails.BuildingID,
    "StartDate":$scope.projectDetails.StartDate,
    "EndDate":$scope.projectDetails.EndDate,
    "Status":$scope.projectDetails.Status,
    "ContactPerson":$scope.projectDetails.ContactPerson,
    "Contractor":$scope.projectDetails.Contractor,
    "ProjectManager":$scope.projectDetails.ProjectManager,
    "Works": $scope.projectDetails.works,
    "Comments":$scope.updatecomments,
    };
    
    $http.post("https://happybuildings.sim.vuw.ac.nz/api/sooleandr/update.project.json", updateproject).then(
      function success(){
        alert("Project Successfully Posted");
        },
        function error(){
          alert("Error: Couldn't post to server");
        }
    )
};
```

It posts perfectly fine but it currently overrides the comments. I want to be able to add a new comment and still keep all the past comments. So I want to be able to push/add the comments into the full POST.JSON array.
Hope this makes a bit more sense

Comment: Please add a sample of the input JSON and a sample of desired output

Comment: Do you want to delete the old array and insert completely new elements? I couldn't understand the logic that you require from the question

Comment: How do you retrieve existing comments from the JSON file?
May be your JSON file wasn't read properly and your code assume that existing comments never exist.

Comment: Everything is working completely fine with the POST and GET for my JSON files. I want to be able to add a new comment to the existing JSON file. We are only given the link to update the whole project so I need to keep all the project information the same and be able to add in a new comment to the existing data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, updating answer after looking at provided code.

It appears you may be under the impression that $scope.projectDetails.Comments is a JSON string, when, in fact.. it's the actual Comments array.

I would try this for the addnewcomment function:

```
//ADDING NEW COMMENTS
//add new comment within project
$scope.updatecomments = undefined;
$scope.addnewcomment = function() {
    $scope.updatecomments = $scope.updatecomments || $scope.projectDetails.Comments;
    $scope.updatecomments.push({
        "Author": "test",
        "Text": $scope.NewComment
    })
}
```

**IF** it just so happens to be a JSON string (highly unlikely), then I would update the combine function to this:

```
$scope.combineComments = function (){
    var jsonStr = $scope.projectDetails.Comments;
    var obj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
          
    obj.push({"Author":"Test","Text":$scope.NewComment});
          jsonStr = JSON.stringify(obj);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
I'm adding another answer from my original because of the possibility things will break when there are no updated comments

```js
//ADDING NEW COMMENTS
//add new comment within project
$scope.addnewcomment = function() {
  $scope.projectDetails.Comments.push({
        "Author": "test",
        "Text": $scope.NewComment
    })
}
```

Then in the POST, change to:

`"Comments":$scope.projectDetails.Comments`

Comment: When I run the combineComments function it only shows the new Comments. It overrides all the old comments

Comment: I tried the first one and it broke the code. The second one I'm confused about because what do I put into my POST function? I tried the jsonStr to post but it didn't post anything.

Comment: If the first one broke the code, it's because $scope.projectDetails is null at the time the addnewcomments function is defined.  Now knowing this, i changed the answer to account for this.  Disregard the whole combine part of my answer because you now realize that $scope.projectDetails.Comments is **not** a JSON string

Comment: Thank you so much! you are a lifesaver!

Comment: I'm glad it worked out, but I thought of the situation where there aren't any new comments and this will break the code.  I've edited my answer to what I believe is the best solution

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out how to combine the two with

```
$scope.combinecomments = [];
   $scope.combine = function (){
     $scope.combinecomments.push($scope.projectDetails.Comments);
     $scope.combinecomments.push($scope.updatecomments);
   }
```

Except now it doesn't post the combined comments

```
$scope.ProjectID='$scope.ProjectID';
    $scope.Name = '$scope.Name';
    $scope.BuildingID = '$scope.BuildingID';
    $scope.StartDate = '$scope.StartDate';
    $scope.EndDate = '$scope.EndDate';
    $scope.Status = '$scope.Status';
    $scope.ContactPerson = '$scope.ContactPerson';
    $scope.Contractor ='$scope.Contractor';
    $scope.ProjectManager = '$scope.ProjectManager';
    $scope.Works = '$scope.works';
    $scope.Comments ='$scope.comments';

$scope.updateProject = function (projectDetails){
  
  var updateproject = {
    "ProjectID":$scope.projectDetails.ProjectID,
    "Name":$scope.projectDetails.Name,
    "BuildingID":$scope.projectDetails.BuildingID,
    "StartDate":$scope.projectDetails.StartDate,
    "EndDate":$scope.projectDetails.EndDate,
    "Status":$scope.projectDetails.Status,
    "ContactPerson":$scope.projectDetails.ContactPerson,
    "Contractor":$scope.projectDetails.Contractor,
    "ProjectManager":$scope.projectDetails.ProjectManager,
    "Works": $scope.projectDetails.works,
    "Comments":$scope.combinecomments,
    };
    
    $http.post("https://happybuildings.sim.vuw.ac.nz/api/sooleandr/update.project.json", updateproject).then(
      function success(){
        alert("Project Successfully Posted");
        },
        function error(){
          alert("Error: Couldn't post to server");
        }
    )
};
```

It successfully posts the project except for the comments. It doesn't seem to like my combined array. When I post `$scope.updatecomments` it will post that but not the `$scope.combinecomments`.

I'll make a new question for this.